# Old passport info: what if old passport were lost?

Tags: visas, passports, australia

I need to send an old passport to Australian embassy for visa application. If this is to do so what happen with those people who have lost their old passport. Do they still send a visa application with new current passport?

Comment: In most cases a transfer of conditions requires the visa itself. If you lost your passport and there's a current visa, you will need to reapply.  But the rules are highly dependent upon country and immigration status and some other conditions.  Knowing this, do you want a formal answer? Or are you OK with a comment?